# ESM over apt-acher-ng

Tags: apt-cacher-ng, esm

I have a ubuntu 16.04 Server without Internet Connection. It gets updates over a central apt-cacher-ng server.
I have copied the ubuntu-esm-infra.list to the central server to `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/` and restarted the apt-cacher but our 16.04 ubuntu is still getting the error:

```
Ign:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease
 Fehl:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security Release
 Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
Fehl:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates Release
Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

E: Das Depot »https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security Release« enthält keine    Release-Datei.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

What can i do to solve the problem?

Many thanks in advanced
R.

Comment: I'm not sure about *apt-cacher-ng*, but for *squid-deb-proxy* I have already added *esm.ubuntu.com* to the corresponding config file */etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/20-ubuntu* . This removes 403 error.

Comment: Refer to https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19582/end-of-support-notice-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-reaches-end-of-standard-suppo?cb=1  ESM doesn't make your question on-topic here as it's covered by your Ubuntu Advantage support if you have it.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: I have no Problem with ubuntu 16.04! I have a problem with apt-cacher-ng and that one is running on Ubuntu 20.04.
The onle thing what i like to no how to add a url to apt-cacher to make it available for server without internet connection.

Comment: Put this one

      PassThroughPattern: ^(.*):443$

in acng.conf of apt-cacher Server solved my Problem!
Many Thank's to all